# Facebook graph - Ajax / JSON showing url 'shares'

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, facebook

I'm very new to using JSON and struggling to get to grips with retrieving data from an object and printing to HTML. The basic requirement is that i retrieve the url share count from facebook which aparently as its public data, i don't need to mess around with access tokens.

My script so far

```
$.ajax(
  {
  url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://google.co.uk',
  success: function(json)
    {
      console.log(json); 
    }       
});
```

Which returns the following as an object in the console.

```
[object Object] {
 http://google.co.uk: [object Object] {
 comments: 5,
 id: "http://google.co.uk",
 shares: 321364
 }
}
```

So i can see the 'shares' data is there but how do i access it and print into a div? I've tried appending it to the 'sharecount' div like this

```
jQuery(response_container).append('<div id="sharecount">Shares: ' + shares + '</div>');
```

But i'm just fumbling in the dark and could use some guidance. Most guides on this seem to be out of date and recommend using the old FQL method.

I have a JSBIN here if anyone wants to take pity on me!

http://jsbin.com/qinutanotu/edit?html,console,output

thanks

UPDATE

I've now changed it to this which works

```
  <script>
   $.ajax(
   {
   url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://google.co.uk',
   success: function(json)
    {
      var urlshares = (json['http://google.co.uk'].shares)
      $("#sharecount").append(urlshares);
    }       
   });    
  </script>
  <div id="sharecount"></div>
```

UPDATE #2

graph.facebook.com seems to sometimes not return 'shares' and this might be to do with there being no shares for that url. Rather than returning '0' it returns nothing at all. To fix this i've replaced append with html and given the div a default value of 0 which gets replaced if the url has a share count passed back

```
  <script>
   $.ajax(
   {
   url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://google.co.uk',
   success: function(json)
    {
      var urlshares = (json['http://google.co.uk'].shares)
      $("#sharecount").html(urlshares);
    }       
   });    
  </script>
  <div id="sharecount">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook uses the URL as key here, so you need `json['http://google.co.uk']` first to access the inner object, and then `json['http://google.co.uk'].shares` to access the shares value.

(`http://google.co.uk` contains characters that make it impossible to use the dot notation to access the property using that key, therefor the `['http://google.co.uk']` has to be used here.)

Comment: thanks a lot. Makes perfect sense. Original post updated